# Unicyclic graph

Tags: graph-theory

Please help me to know the reason for the following fact.

Let $G$ be an unicyclic graph with $n$ vertices and  $u$ be a vertex of $G$. Also let $d_u$ is degree of $u$ and  $\Delta_{adg}(G)=max\{d_v+d_u | uv\in E(G)\}$. If $\Delta_{adg}(G)\leq n-1$, then $d_{j1}+d_{j2}+\ldots+d_{jd_j}\leq n+1$, where $v_{j1},\ldots,v_{jd_i}$ denote the adjacent vertices to the vertex $v_i$.